Is it safe to connect all ground (0V) lines in my power supply design?
I’m designing a power supply for a device, and I have a basic question, but I’m concerned about making a mistake and damaging the circuit. My question is whether it's possible or if there would be any issues if I connect all the ground (0V) lines together in the circuit.


The grounds are the least of your worries. The mains input is cancelling itself out.

Do they need to be tied together anyway? Is it important for your device that they are?


As numbered:

Already is (3)
Already is (3)
Ground connection here
Ground connection here
No, or lift (4) to ground this
Most likely, yes
Note there's no connection here; this (negative?) supply and IC does nothing.

The full wave rectifier from centertapped winding motif is a common way to make bipolar power supplies; this is seen in the center-above section (2-3 and related).  Note this is identical to a FWCT rectifier (one diode from each end of CT winding, to a single positive output; or one diode from single negative output to each end of winding), doubled up symmetrically, so we get the middle ground for free when the winding is tapped like this.
In (4-5), this would conflict, where (5) is below (4) by one-half the total rectified voltage of that winding.  Making both connections would short it out.  Only make one or the other.  If I had to guess, I would guess they wanted (5) -V to be a fixed supply, and the +V to be adjustable from -V to full +V (hence the variable resistor and source follower).  The +V is also current limited (but not the -V!).
Also worth noting there's no fuse indicated at the mains input.  This might be a board schematic and a fuse, switch, filter, etc. might be provided elsewhere, I don't know, but just in case.

Yes, I forgot to add a connection to the last circuit. Should I connect points 1, 2, 5, and 6 to the same ground and lift the ground at point 4? The circuit at point 5 is for a regulated 132V output using an N-channel MOSFET.

I don't know what you're using the voltages for, but that would be a valid (non-blowing-up) combination, yes.  Mind that that's not a regulator, it's a variable proportional voltage, and doesn't even have additional ripple filtering (often, a similar circuit is used with a filter capacitor from gate to common).
